# Wordpress Migration Post Problems

Tags: php, wordpress

how are you, thank you first for reading my message. I am currently working on a website, created with wordpress, the website has been compromised with security flaws, because when wordpress was installed they did it with a version of php 5.2, also the website is working with Wordpress version 5.3.4.

I am looking to make a clean copy of the website, first to be able to install the latest version of php to date 7.4, since the website generates errors when I try to change the version of php by force.

I am looking to make a copy of the post, with their respective featured images, using the wordpress exporter I have managed to export the entries without problem, but I cannot export the featured image.

I have tried to do various things:

**1**- export the entries, and then manually upload the images to the uploads folder

it has not worked

I don't want to migrate the entire site as the template has some styling errors that need to be fixed.

There is a way to migrate blog posts with the featured image, but I haven't figured it out so far, can you give me a hand? maybe a plugin? or how can I copy the posts directly to the database from php my admin, any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are various plugins which exports and imports posts into a Wordpress website.

I usually use the below plugin to import Posts from one WP website to another.

Export Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-exporter/
Import Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

Install both the plugins in the website where you want to export. Setup  will create a CSV file with posts.
After that, install the Importer plugin alone in the site where you want the pots to be imported. Now, Upload the CSV file to import the posts.

If this answer works for you, do accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Please don't promote a plugin as an answer. Also, as noted in someone else's comment, this is off-topic here (there's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to WordPress, also linked to in the comment under the question).